Ubuntu 22.04.1 crash with message "rcu_preempt detected expedited stalls on CPUs" on terminal
I Installed Ubuntu 22.04.1 on my old PC recently. But it crashes a few times every day. At first I thought it was due to motherboard incompatibility so I change the motherboard from GIGABYTE B450M Aorus elite to MSI B550M PRO-VDH WIFI and reinstall Linux. It did improved at some level, since with the old motherboard I even canot install Ubuntu and switch to Debian and now crash happened less per day.
BTW this PC works pretty well on Windows 11. Have run MEMTEST86 for 4 passes and pass the test.
Here is text from dmesg: https://www.mediafire.com/file/e4yw64m63o16urk/dmesg.txt/file
Hardware probe: https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=9b7f62afeb
And here is part of dmesg:
[  460.620427] watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#1 stuck for 26s! [argocd-applicat:10862]
[  460.621697] Modules linked in: ipt_REJECT nf_reject_ipv4 xt_multiport xt_mark xt_comment rfcomm veth xt_nat xt_tcpudp xt_conntrack nft_chain_nat xt_MASQUERADE nf_nat nf_conntrack_netlink nf_conntrack nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv4 xfrm_user xfrm_algo xt_addrtype nft_compat nf_tables libcrc32c nfnetlink br_netfilter bridge stp llc cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep overlay binfmt_misc nvidia_uvm(POE) intel_rapl_msr intel_rapl_common edac_mce_amd nvidia_drm(POE) nvidia_modeset(POE) kvm irqbypass crct10dif_pclmul polyval_clmulni polyval_generic ghash_clmulni_intel sha256_ssse3 sha1_ssse3 aesni_intel snd_hda_codec_realtek crypto_simd snd_hda_codec_generic cryptd iwlmvm snd_hda_codec_hdmi ledtrig_audio nvidia(POE) snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg snd_intel_sdw_acpi mac80211 snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core snd_hwdep libarc4 snd_pcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi btusb iwlwifi btrtl btbcm snd_seq btintel btmtk snd_seq_device nls_iso8859_1 rapl wmi_bmof snd_timer bluetooth input_leds k10temp cfg80211 ccp snd
[  460.621798]  joydev drm_kms_helper ecdh_generic soundcore ecc video mac_hid sch_fq_codel msr parport_pc ppdev lp parport drm efi_pstore ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_logitech_hidpp hid_logitech_dj hid_generic usbhid hid ucsi_ccg typec_ucsi typec nvme crc32_pclmul r8169 nvme_core i2c_piix4 i2c_nvidia_gpu ahci i2c_ccgx_ucsi xhci_pci realtek libahci xhci_pci_renesas nvme_common wmi gpio_amdpt
[  460.621847] CPU: 1 PID: 10862 Comm: argocd-applicat Tainted: P           OE      6.5.0-27-generic #28~22.04.1-Ubuntu
[  460.621850] Hardware name: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. MS-7C95/B550M PRO-VDH WIFI (MS-7C95), BIOS 2.D0 12/12/2022
[  460.621852] RIP: 0010:native_queued_spin_lock_slowpath+0x26e/0x300
[  460.621859] Code: 81 c5 00 3f 03 00 49 81 ff ff 1f 00 00 0f 87 91 00 00 00 4e 03 2c fd 40 5b c9 a6 4d 89 65 00 41 8b 44 24 08 85 c0 75 0b f3 90 <41> 8b 44 24 08 85 c0 74 f5 49 8b 14 24 48 85 d2 74 05 0f 0d 0a eb
[  460.621862] RSP: 0018:ffffb7695489bcd8 EFLAGS: 00000246
[  460.621864] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: ffffa0dd64062308 RCX: 0000000000000000
[  460.621867] RDX: 00000000000005ff RSI: 0000000017fdefd9 RDI: ffffa0dd64062308
[  460.621868] RBP: ffffb7695489bd00 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000000000
[  460.621870] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000000 R12: ffffa0e34ea73f00
[  460.621872] R13: ffffffffa787cf20 R14: 0000000000080000 R15: 00000000000005fe
[  460.621874] FS:  000000c000100090(0000) GS:ffffa0e34ea40000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[  460.621876] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[  460.621878] CR2: 000000c00035f6e0 CR3: 00000001f210c000 CR4: 0000000000350ee0
[  460.621880] Call Trace:
[  460.621882]  <IRQ>
[  460.621886]  ? show_regs+0x6d/0x80
[  460.621891]  ? watchdog_timer_fn+0x1d8/0x240
[  460.621895]  ? __pfx_watchdog_timer_fn+0x10/0x10
[  460.621898]  ? __hrtimer_run_queues+0x112/0x2a0
[  460.621902]  ? srso_return_thunk+0x5/0x10
[  460.621906]  ? hrtimer_interrupt+0xf6/0x250
[  460.621911]  ? __sysvec_apic_timer_interrupt+0x62/0x140
[  460.621916]  ? sysvec_apic_timer_interrupt+0x8d/0xd0
[  460.621919]  </IRQ>
[  460.621921]  <TASK>
[  460.621923]  ? asm_sysvec_apic_timer_interrupt+0x1b/0x20
[  460.621931]  ? native_queued_spin_lock_slowpath+0x26e/0x300
[  460.621936]  _raw_spin_lock+0x3f/0x60
[  460.621940]  __mutex_lock.constprop.0+0x261/0x7a0
[  460.621942]  ? srso_return_thunk+0x5/0x10
[  460.621945]  ? _raw_spin_unlock_bh+0x1d/0x30
[  460.621950]  __mutex_lock_slowpath+0x13/0x20
[  460.621953]  mutex_lock+0x3c/0x50
[  460.621956]  do_epoll_ctl+0x30d/0x860
[  460.621961]  ? inet_dgram_connect+0x42/0xe0
[  460.621967]  __x64_sys_epoll_ctl+0x6e/0xb0
[  460.621971]  do_syscall_64+0x5b/0x90
[  460.621977]  ? srso_return_thunk+0x5/0x10
[  460.621979]  ? exit_to_user_mode_prepare+0x30/0xb0
[  460.621982]  ? srso_return_thunk+0x5/0x10
[  460.621985]  ? syscall_exit_to_user_mode+0x37/0x60
[  460.621987]  ? srso_return_thunk+0x5/0x10
[  460.621989]  ? do_syscall_64+0x67/0x90
[  460.621992]  ? do_syscall_64+0x67/0x90
[  460.621995]  ? sysvec_apic_timer_interrupt+0x4b/0xd0
[  460.621999]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x6e/0xd8
[  460.622002] RIP: 0033:0x40720e
[  460.622023] Code: 48 83 ec 38 e8 13 00 00 00 48 83 c4 38 5d c3 cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc 49 89 f2 48 89 fa 48 89 ce 48 89 df 0f 05 <48> 3d 01 f0 ff ff 76 15 48 f7 d8 48 89 c1 48 c7 c0 ff ff ff ff 48
[  460.622026] RSP: 002b:000000c0034cba90 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 00000000000000e9
[  460.622029] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 0000000000000003 RCX: 000000000040720e
[  460.622030] RDX: 000000000000000b RSI: 0000000000000001 RDI: 0000000000000003
[  460.622032] RBP: 000000c0034cbae8 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000000000
[  460.622034] R10: 000000c0034cbad4 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 0000000000000000
[  460.622035] R13: 000000c000100000 R14: 000000c00277e9c0 R15: 000000000000006c

Thanks in advance.

The hardware issue is highly suspected because the stack printed after crash is not same every time, so it may not be software issue.
After some tweaks of BIOS hardware setting and experiment, it turn out to be the CPU ryzen 3600X issue. It works at base frequency of 3.8Ghz by default. But when running linux at 3.8Ghz seems to be very unstable, even after boosting the fans and turn off CPU boost setting mannuly.
Finnaly after setting the base frequency at 3.6Ghz (just like its brother ryzen 3600), it runs smoothly and the system never crashes again. Precision Boost Overdrive is no need to turn off and fan setting is kept default setting, by the way.
